# Avoid y axis overlap by factors strips when applying useOuterStrips ? {latticeExtra}

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have a combination plot per two factors. As I am using double Y scale, I can't easily use ggplot2, so I am using {lattice}.

When I apply my strips o the edges (by useOuterStrips) my Y scale is overlapped by strip with factor name. How can I avoid the overlapping? Is there also a way to switch strips of var2 on the left side to the right of the plot?

my dummy data:

```
mtcars$HP <- equal.count(mtcars$hp)
a<-useOuterStrips(xyplot(mpg ~ disp | factor(cyl) + HP, mtcars),
               strip.left = TRUE,
               strip = strip.custom(style = 4),)

b<-useOuterStrips(xyplot(qsec ~ disp | factor(cyl) + HP, mtcars),
                  strip.left = TRUE,
                  strip = strip.custom(style = 4),)

doubleYScale(a,b,  add.ylab2=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the record this is a terrible idea - there's a reason it wasn't implemented in ggplot2. There is likely a better way to show what you need.

Re the overlap issue, you can probably fix it up with something like

`update(p, 
       par.settings = list(
           layout.widths = list(left.padding = 10)))`

cheers

Comment: Hi @FelixAndrews, thank you for your quick answer. However, this solution just changes the width of my columns, but doesn't shift the scale further apart from the strip... Maybe there will be another way how to make it? And yes, I may agree, this type of plotting may lead to to some misunderstanding but I really think is the best one for me now.. but I'll start to think about different types. Thank you a lot, I really appreciate your help.